# Databricks is "Updating the Delta table's state"

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I'm reading and joining multiple delta tables from a Datalake and store the result back to another Deltalake location. When doing so, Databricks is showing me :
[image]

Depending on how many delta tables I join with each other, this can take up to very long time. Even tough the joining itself would just take up to a few minutes, the state update takes up to an hour.

What is happening when I see `Updating the Delta table's state`? Can I somehow optimize this?

Comment: You can ref : https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html